# Find path from A to B which length ≈ L

Tags: graphs

I have an undirected weighted graph.

I want to find the path from A to B which length (sum of the weights) is as close as possible to a specific value "L".

To do that, I have been doing a DFS to check all the possible paths... When L is relatively small, it's ok. But when I ask for a bigger L, it takes too much time to complete. I added some criteria to stop searching useless paths but that cannot solve the problem.

So I was wondering how to do what I am searching for. Is DFS the only solution ? I thought about genetic algorithms but I don't know if it would work.

Thank you !

Comment: Can you pass multiple times on the same edges ? Like doing back and forth over one edge ?

Comment: Actually no, because I am trying to do a program that finds a trail of a specific length in km for when I want to do a run... So that would be pretty boring to go and go back on the same road over again :D But your idea seems pretty good. I could try to take 3 points that will be part of the path, and perform that Dijkstra's from these 3 points...

Comment: A quite hard problem indeed. DFS is by nature supposed to find the shortest path so it may not be adapted.

Comment: Sorry I answered on the wrong topic on my last answer. I think someone found a solution. Perform Dijkstra's from A and from B. Then find a node which distance from A + distance from B is approximately L. That's way more efficient  than DFS.

Comment: Does it have to be a simple path?  Or is it OK to visit the same vertex more than once?  Please edit the question to clarify it rather than leaving information in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are no known efficient algorithms for your problem. Consider the case where every edge has weight $1$ and there are $n$ vertices in the graph. A path from $A$ to $B$ with weight (approximately) $n-1$ is (approximately) a Hamiltonian path from $A$ to $B$ and finding Hamiltonian paths is **NP**-hard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I will try to find approximations then. Someone had the idea to perform Dijkstra from node A and then from node B. So I will have for each node of the graph the distance to A and to B. Then I have to check foreach node, which one has distA + distB approximately equal to what I am searching for. Think that will do the job :)